# How to trigger build in Jenkins immediately after the code check-in

Tags: svn, jenkins

How do I trigger the build in Jenkins once the code is committed?

1. Jenkins is installed and the build is can be triggered manually.
2. Below are the SVN version details.

   - TortoiseSVN 1.8.1, Build 24570 - 32 Bit , 2013/07/22 18:28:29
   - Subversion 1.8.1, -release
   - apr 1.4.8
   - apr-util 1.5.2
   - serf 1.3.0
   - OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
   - zlib 1.2.8
3. Jenkins URL: "localhost:8080/job/TestProject/"

Answer (score 17):

To have the build triggered immediately once the code is committed, you'll need to have something notifying Jenkins.

However you can configure your job to poll your SCM regularly (at my shop we poll our Mercurial repositories every 5 minutes) for new changes and build if there are new changes.

For this, in the **Build Triggers** section, you check the **Poll SCM** checkbox, and fill in a cron expression in the textarea. For polling every 5 minutes, we use

```
H/5 * * * *
```

Note that we used to use

```
*/5 * * * *
```

but replacing the left `*` by the `H` allows Jenkins to avoid polling for all projects at the same time (it will then poll every 5 minutes, but not necessarily at 0, 5, 10, etc. minutes.

One can also trigger builds remotely by checking **Trigger builds remotely** and specifying a token in the textbox. Then a simple contact from a script to the relevant URL will trigger the build.

```
JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build?token=TOKEN_NAME
```

(This option might require some particular permissions to set up, or some particular global configuration, as it seems it's not available to OP.)

For the post-commit hook solution, see [Jenkins' Subversion Plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin), with the important parts below:

> Jenkins can poll Subversion repositories for changes, and while this is reasonably efficient, this can only happen up to every once a minute, so you may still have to wait a full minute before Jenkins detects a change.
>
> To reduce this delay, you can set up a [post commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) so the Subversion repository can notify Jenkins whenever a change is made to that repository. To do this, put the following script in your post-commit file (in the $REPOSITORY/hooks directory):
>
> ```
> REPOS="$1"
> REV="$2"
> UUID=`svnlook uuid $REPOS`
> /usr/bin/wget \
>   --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
>   --post-data "`svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
>   --output-document "-" \
>   --timeout=2 \
>   http://server/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
> ```

(It is really recommended to read the full documentation for information related to the configuration or for a more robust script.)

Comment: Is there any changes or configuration need on the SVN end basically on the SVN hook where it notifies the Jenkins that the code is commited.

Comment: If you want it to be immediate, you'll need some svn hook to notify jenkins (you enable the **Trigger builds remotely** check box and have your svn hook contact that url); otherwise (the periodic poll method) you just need to have svn configured to allow access to jenkins, which I believe is already the case otherwise it would have a hard time building at all ;)

Comment: Could you please let me know how to configure the svn hook.

Comment: Also i am not able to find the options in Build Triggers. Below are the option
1. Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built 
2. Build after other projects are built 
3. Build periodically 
4. Build when another project is promoted 
5. Poll SCM

Comment: **Poll SCM** is the option I recommended for periodic poll of the SCM. The absence of **Trigger builds remotely** might be linked to a global configuration of your jenkins instance.

Comment: Could you please let me know the steps to configure the svn hook.

Comment: Note that I added a link to the jenkins plugin documentation in my answer, as it seems it can be used without that **Trigger builds remotely** option. However read it all and don't just rely on the quick excerpt I put in my answer ;)

Comment: I don't have the first clue on how to create a svn hook so I couldn't help for that. However the jenkins svn plugin documentation for which i added the link in my answer, as well as the link to svn's hook creation documentation should be a good start for you.

Comment: My post-commit bat looks something like this

Comment: SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2
SET UUID=`svnlook uuid %REPOS%`
C:/wget_for_win/wget \
 --header="Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
 --post-data="svnlook changed --revision %REV% %REPOS%"
 --output-document="-"
 --timeout=2
 http://localhost:8080/jenkins/subversion/%UUID%/notifyCommit?rev=%REV%

What should be this value "C:/wget_for_win/wget" in the post-commit.bat file.
And also in the global configuration i dont find the option to enable the trigger build remotely. Will check again.